# Memory Leak Issue with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, memory-leaks

I am using:
angularJS - 1.3.x
browser - IE11
plugins -

```
['LocalStorageModule', 'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'ngCacheBuster', 'datatables', 'datatables.columnfilter', 'datatables.bootstrap', 'ngTable', 
    'angular.filter', 'xeditable', 'smart-table', 'ui.calendar', 'pageslide-directive', 'security', 'utils', 'ngTagsInput', 'xtForm', 
    'ngAnimate', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.datepicker', 'ngToast','mgcrea.ngStrap.select','mgcrea.ngStrap.typeahead','mgcrea.ngStrap.tooltip' , 'mgcrea.ngStrap.popover', 'ngIntlTelInput','textAngular', 'fcsa-number', 'ngFileSaver', 'ngIdle']
```

We have a "summary page" which is the home page of our application and displays a list of deals using pagination. User can click on any deal and can navigate to deal details screen. User has the facility to edit deal info on the deal details screen.

We are facing a Memory Leakage issue in the following scenario:

1. User navigates from summary to deal details screen.
2. ***Edits a field with a popup modal containing a textarea.***
3. Either saves the info or directly navigates to summary page, we see a spike under memory usage which causes the screen to freeze.

**This is only happening when we are using IE, this doesn't happen on chrome.** 
We have tried:

1. Removing nested ng-repeats
2. Tried removing plugins to find out if any plugin is causing this issue
3. etc. etc...

Could you please suggest whatelse can cause this issue and is there any fixes or workarounds for this?

Comment: angular with IE seems terrifying.

Comment: Install the Batarang plugin - https://github.com/spalger/angularjs-batarang and look for the 'Performance' tab - that'll indicate the number of 'watches'.  Also, look for any event handlers (DOM or otherwise) that might get added but not destroyed.  Also, listen for ''$destroy" event on the scope and see how the memory looks like before and after the page navigation.